# Table Number Formatting & Text Added HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have want to add table on my HTML Code
But I want it as number formatted
For Example I want it formatted as this : Rp. 100.000) 
So the "Rp." need to be automatic added on begining of the cell and the number format will as above..
Sorry for my bad English, here's my code and thank you for your time :

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<title>Preventive Maintenance Analyzer Tools</title>

<div id="container" style="width:1350px;height:600px">
<div id="header" style="background-color:#094AB2;width:1350px;height:50px">
<h1 style="font-family:verdana;color : white;">Preventive Maintenance Analyzer Tools</font></h1></div></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#DAE0DA;height:560px;width:150px;float:left;">
<img src = "taxi.png" width = "130" height = "130" align = "center"><br><br><br><br><br>
<font size="4"><a href = "http://localhost/home.php">HOME</a><br><br></font>
<font size="4"><a href = "http://localhost/entry.html">CREATE NEW</a><br><br></font>
<font size="4"><a href = "">SETTINGS</a></font><br><br><br><br><br></br>
<img src = "taxi2.png" width = "140" height = "130" align = "center">
</div>

<h2><center>Silahkan Isi Detail Form Dibawah Ini</center></h2>

<div align = "center">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Detail Onsite</b></legend>

Dari :
<select name="dari">
<option value="co">Cyber Office</option>    
</select><br><br>`

Tujuan PM :
<select id="tujuan" name="tujuan">
<option value="abb">ABB Sakti Industri</option>
<option value="ace">ACE Life Assurance</option>
<option value="cigna">Asuransi Cigna</option>
<option value="bahana">Bahana Securities</option>
<option value="cimb">Bank CIMB</option>
<option value="dki">Bank DKI</option>
<option value="icbc">Bank ICBC Indonesia</option>
<option value="bni">Bank BNI</option>
<option value="courts">Courts Retail Indonesia</option>
<option value="ffi">Frisian Flag Indonesia</option>
<option value="gel">Great Eastern Life Indonesia</option>
<option value="komatsu">Komatsu Indonesia</option>
<option value="pertamina">Pertamina EP</option>
<option value="rscm">Rumah Sakit Cipto Mangunkusomo (RSCM)</option>
<option value="siloam">Siloam Hospital</option>
<option value="takeda">Takeda Indonesia</option>
<option value="vni">Visionet</option>
</select><br><br>

Cuaca : 
<select id="cuaca" name="cuaca">
<option value="normal">Normal / Cerah</option>
<option value="gerimis">Gerimis</option>
<option value="hujan">Hujan</option>
</select><br><br>

Faktor Eksternal (contoh demo, banjir, macet luar biasa dll) : <br>
<select id="fe" name="fe">
<option value="false">Tidak Ada</option>
<option value="true">Ada</option>
</select><br><br>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit">Submit</a>

</form>
</div>


<div id="output" style="display:none">


      <center><h2>Estimasi Claim</h2></center>
      <table border="4" ALIGN="center" >
      <tr>
        <th>Keterangan</th>
        <th>Estimasi</th>
       </tr>
        <td> Estimasi Argo Taxi </td>
        <td align="right" id="output_t1"></td>
        <tr>
        <td> Cuaca </td>
        <td align="right" id="output_t2"></td>
        <tr>
        <td> Faktor Eksternal </td>
        <td align="right" id="output_t3"></td>
        <tr>
        <td> Total Claim </td>
        <td align="right" span class="price" id="output_t4"></td>
        <tr>
        </table>

        <br><center><b>Selamat Atas Kemenangan Anda, Sampai Jumpa Pada Kemenangan Berikutnya</b></center>

 </div>

<script>
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){

  document.getElementById('output').style.display = "block";

  var tujuan        = document.getElementById('tujuan').value;
  var cuaca         = document.getElementById('cuaca').value;
  var fe            = document.getElementById('fe').value;

  var t1; 
  var t2; 
  var t3;
  var t4;

  switch(tujuan){

    case "abb":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "ace":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "cigna":
      t1 = 170000;
      break;

    case "bahana":
      t1 = 375000;
      break;

    case "cimb":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "dki":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "icbc":
      t1 = 330000;
      break;

    case "bni":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;  

     case "courts":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;

    case "ffi":
      t1 = 430000;
      break;

    case "gel":
      t1 = 360000;
      break;

     case "komatsu":
      t1 = 580000;
      break;

    case "pertamina":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "rscm":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "siloam":
      t1 = 50000;
      break;

    case "takeda":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;

    case "visionet":
      t1 = 20000;
      break;

  } 

  switch(cuaca){

    case "normal":
      t2 = 0;
      break;

    case "gerimis":
      t2 = 20000;
      break;

    case "hujan":
      t2 = 40000;
      break;

    }

   if(fe == 'true'){
    t3    = 40000;
  }
  else{
    t3    = 0;
  }
  t4 = t1 + t2 + t3;
  console.log(t4);

  document.getElementById('output_t1').innerHTML = t1; 
  document.getElementById('output_t2').innerHTML = t2;
  document.getElementById('output_t3').innerHTML = t3;   
  document.getElementById('output_t4').innerHTML = t4;
}
</script>

</body>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#094AB2;clear:both;text-align:center;">
<font color = "white">Copyright : M. Rinaldy Aulia 2015</font></div>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your data coming from? Dis you mean your values must be placed into output_tx cells??

Comment: Show us what you've tried in JS as well.

Comment: Thank you all, I have added all my source code..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to ensure that your numbers do not read "370000" but should instead read "Rp. 370 000", or "45000" should read "Rp. 45 000"

If this is correct, use a function that will format your numbers.  I've created one below called rp_beautifier and have also included some of your sample code on how it might be implemented.  Hopefully I understood correctly and this helps!

---

Here is the function (on line 3, we add "Rp. " and also a space after the $1.  If it were USD it would be "$1," instead of "$1 ")

```
function rp_beautifier(someNumber){
    someNumber = parseFloat(someNumber).toFixed(0);
    someNumber = "Rp. " + String(someNumber).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ")
    return someNumber;
}
```

And here is how you can call it

```
document.getElementById('output_t1').innerHTML = rp_beautifier(t1); 
document.getElementById('output_t2').innerHTML = rp_beautifier(t2);
document.getElementById('output_t3').innerHTML = rp_beautifier(t3);   
document.getElementById('output_t4').innerHTML = rp_beautifier(t4);
```